# Can Access tokens be intercepted in Authorization Code flow OAuth?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have been reading different flows of OAuth and have confusion about the Authorization Code flow. It is said that Authorization Code Flow is more secure because even if the authorization code is hijacked while transfer, it is useless to the hacker because the the hacker would need the client id and client secret to acquire the access token - but what if when the client requests for access token after receiving the authorization code, the hacker hacks the transmission and get the access token?
I don't know but it looks like the Authorization code is only adding an extra layer of security but not actually completely securing the access tokens. 
Am I right? Please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

The typical use case for an Authorization Code flow is that the token request (i.e. the one that exchanges the Authorization Code for an access token) is done over a TLS protected backchannel which means that the attacker cannot get to it - unless he's able to break SSL in which case there are much bigger problems.

But for front-channel use case, i.e. an in-browser Javascript application or Single Page Application you are right: a hacker could almost just as easy intercept the token request as the redirect. That is also why that use case cannot use a confidential client since the secret would be too easily exposed.

Comment: Hello, you said "Authorization Code flow is that the token request (i.e. the one that exchanges the Authorization Code for an access token) is done over a TLS protected backchannel " but if it this flow is used over TLS protected backchannel, why can't the auth server return an access token instead of authentication code when a user authenticates an app?

Comment: Because that would be in the front channel with the authorization code flow, by definition

Comment: Hi @HansZ. I disagree with the second section of your answer. The RFC6749 do not prevent public clients to use the Authorization Code flow.
To prevent the issuance of an access token using an intercepted auth. code with this client type, the RFC7636 introduces a code verifier. The draft https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-03#section-5.1.1 indicates that it is the prefered way for native apps.

Comment: Not debating that but AFAICT the OPs confusion/question is more about web clients vs in-browser clients

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization code flow makes sense when you have a frontend client which also has access to a backend which can securely talk to the auth server.

The flow would be as follows:

- The frontend client redirects the user to the auth server url
- the auth server (after login), redirects the user back to the frontend client redirectUri
- the frontend client extracts the code from this url and passes it on the backend.
- the backend then exchanges this code for an access token by directly interacting with the auth server.

The backend to auth server communication is what the hacker can't intercept (easily).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought when I first read about the **authorization code flow**.
And your observation is correct:

If the authorization code is returned to the client application (e.g. SPA) that run's in the user's browser, an attacker could potentially steal the authorization code and use it to potentially gain access. It doesn't matter whether the SPA exchanges the authorization code for an access token directly or via a server. In the first case, the secret would be somewehre in the browser (not good!) and in the second case, the server could be used by an attacker to exchange the authorization code for an access token. Using the authorization code flow like this does not give you any real benefit over the outdated **implicit flow**.

To solve this problem, you can either use the **authorization code flow with a web server** OR use the **PKCE-enhanced authorization code flow**.

- Authorization code flow with a web server: The authorization code is NOT returned to the user or SPA but to the web server that exchanges the authorization code for an access token. The server either returns the access token to the user/SPA (could be intercepted again) OR acts as a proxy to call the target resource (probably better) on behalf of the user. However, in the latter case you probably would need to return a session cookie to the user and store the tokens on the server, because you don't want to do this flow for every request.
- [PKCE-enhanced authorization code flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce)